# What is the best way to hyperlink to files. such as .pdf files, when using community builder?

Tags: community-builder, napili, files, hyperlink

We are converting our agency's public website over to a community site using the Napili template, but I am struggling to make files available. Our old website has literally hundres of .pdf files that I need to be able to hyperlink to, or otherwise expose, along with some audio and video files.

Comment: If no authentication is required for those files, then static resources may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are different of ways to expose them

1.Store as an attachment to a custom object

2.Upload all of them as Chatter Files .If there are plenty use data loader to load all inside content version

3.Keep the existing website and create a custom object and store the links as a URL field on a record .

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing all the files in a CRM library within salesforce? If yes, you can create a custom component and add it on the community. I just solved similar use-case for one of my customers, let me know if you are still looking around for a solution, I will explain further. Please note Napili has an out of the box files component but that will show the list of all the folders and the users have to browse through each one to access files (which was cumbersome in my use-case).